# Delphi mORMot No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: postgresql, delphi, delphi-xe8, mormot

I test mORMot component.
I compiled standart demo "28 - Simple RESTful ORM Server"
Run it and get an eror.

Code:

```pascal
var
  aModel: TSQLModel;
  aProps: TSQLDBConnectionProperties;
  aRestServer: TSQLRestServerDB;
  aHttpServer: TSQLHttpServer;
begin
// set logging abilities
SQLite3Log.Family.Level := LOG_VERBOSE;
//SQLite3Log.Family.EchoToConsole := LOG_VERBOSE;
SQLite3Log.Family.PerThreadLog := ptIdentifiedInOnFile;
// ODBC driver e.g. from http://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/odbc/versions/msi


aProps := TODBCConnectionProperties.Create('','Driver=PostgreSQL Unicode'+
  {$ifdef CPU64}'(x64)'+{$endif}';Database=postgres;'+
  'Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5433;UID=postgres;Pwd=postgres','','');

//readln;

try
// get the shared data model
aModel := DataModel;
// use PostgreSQL database for all tables
VirtualTableExternalRegisterAll(aModel,aProps);
try
  // create the main mORMot server
  aRestServer := TSQLRestServerDB.Create(aModel,':memory:',false); // authentication=false
  try
    // optionally execute all PostgreSQL requests in a single thread
    aRestServer.AcquireExecutionMode[execORMGet] := amBackgroundORMSharedThread;
    aRestServer.AcquireExecutionMode[execORMWrite] := amBackgroundORMSharedThread;
    // create tables or fields if missing
    aRestServer.CreateMissingTables;
    // serve aRestServer data over HTTP
    aHttpServer := TSQLHttpServer.Create(SERVER_PORT,[aRestServer],'+',useHttpApiRegisteringURI);
    try
      aHttpServer.AccessControlAllowOrigin := '*'; // allow cross-site AJAX queries
      writeln('Background server is running.'#10);
      write('Press [Enter] to close the server.');
      readln;
    finally
      aHttpServer.Free;
    end;
  finally
    aRestServer.Free;
  end;
finally
  aModel.Free;
end;
finally
  aProps.Free;
end;
end.
```

error

> {"Message":"TODBCLib error: [08001] Could not connect to the server;\nNo connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.\r\n [127.0.0.1:5433]

How to clear it.

Comment: And do you have a postgresql server running on your local machine?

Comment: Yes. PostgreSQL 9.4.

Comment: Well the error is clear, you can't connect via ODBC, this is not a delphi problem but a pure postgres configuration problem. Did you install the ODBC driver, can you connect with PGAdmin, try to make an ODBC connection via ODBC datasources and test it out?

Comment: I instaled psqlodbc_09_03_0400. I made new connection and tested it. It works.

Comment: How did you test? And are you compiling in 64 bit or 32bit? Details matter...

Comment: And are you sure you are on port 5433, default port is 5432?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested it with Delphi Seattle 10 and the ODBC driver from http://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/odbc/versions/msi/psqlodbc_09_03_0400.zip - with no problem.

Ensure your PostgreSQL server has been defined to run on the same port as expected by the source. Edit the `5433` value into `5432` if you used the default port number.

Being paranoid, I try to always change the default port, which reduces network scan attacks (at least from fast scan). I never use port 22 for ssh, nor 5432 for PostgreSQL. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks a lot. PostgreSQL's default port is 5432. Demo use 5433.

Comment: @AndyBirtman: thanks for giving feedback to my questions, NOT... I asked you about the port 1 hour ago...

Comment: @whosrdaddy Thanks for help. I opened my question and read answer. I didn't see your comment ;). Thanks a lot!